# Tenacious badge.

Tags: discussion, badges

> [Tenacious](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/badges/50/tenacious)
> : Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.

Total is total answers or total accepted answers?

I have 6 zero score accepted answers and 24 accepted with 71 total on main site.

### EDIT: Got It!

Comment: There's a bit more of a description at [List of all badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258).

Comment: @Robjon according to list given above , I'll get the badge.The answers must be 10 days old. So i must wait. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not be reading it right (the description is far from clear), but it seems that you have [$6$ zero score accepted answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A67567+score%3A0+isaccepted%3Ayes++is%3Aanswer). Since you have more than $30$ answers, you don't qualify. I don't think that the total refers to only zero score answers.

I just recounted, and you have [$33$ zero score answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A67567+score%3A0++is%3Aanswer). So even if the total refers to only zero score answer, you have less than $20$%.

Just in case this bears, you have [$23$ accepted answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A67567+isaccepted%3Ayes++is%3Aanswer).

**Update:**

As commented by Peter Phipps, the [List of all badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258) has a clearer description:

> #### Tenacious
>
> - silver; awarded once; same family as Unsung Hero (gold)
> - Have more than five accepted answers with a score of zero, and have those zero-score accepted answers account for at least 20% of all your accepted answers
>
>   - Only accepted answers at least ten days old are considered
>   - Community Wiki answers, deleted answers, and self-accepted answers are not included in any calculations
> - Was [originally named Tireless](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/improvements-to-badge-system/).
> - Sources: [How long do Tireless and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57696), a SO team member who checked the source code [in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/284001#284001)

On May $2$, your $5^{\text{th}}$ zero score accepted answer becomes $10$ days old, and that is your $19^{\text{th}}$ accepted answer. Then you should get a Tenacious badge.

Comment: Can't understand. You mean one must have more than 20% of answers accepted of the answers with zero score

Comment: @exploringnet: as I mentioned above, the description of the badge is not clear. From my original reading, I assumed that the number of "zero score accepted answers" needs to be at least $20$% of the number of answers. Perhaps it need only be $20$% of the number of zero score answers, or the number of accepted answers. However, if it were of the number of accepted answers, you would have had that at $5$.

Comment: The 20% is off of the number of accepted answers, but it only counts for answers that are at least 10 days old. At the current state, @exploringnet should get the badge in a few days, as long as none of his 0-score acceptances get voted up or down in the meantime.

Comment: @robjohn  Again a doubt in this. Will the answers with $\pm$ 1 be considered? ie. any answer with net score zero but not zero votes.

Comment: @exploringnet: You have one +1/-1 accepted answer. On May 2, your fifth zero score accepted answer was 10 days old. At that time you had 23 accepted answers. This should have been enough to get your Tenacious badge if the +1/-1 answer counted. On May 4, your sixth zero score accepted answer was 10 days old. At that time, you had 24 accepted answers. Discounting the +1/-1 answer, you had 5 zero score accepted answers which is when you got the badge. From this evidence, I would say that the +1/-1 answer did not count as a zero score answer.